# Spring hibernate not persisting object nodes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I've the following Entity :

```
@Entity
public class Pages {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="page")
private List<Pages_lang> pages_lang;

private long updated;
private Boolean deleted = false;
private long position;
private String icon;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parent")
private List<Pages> children;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Pages parent;
```

And this one :

```
@Entity
public class Pages_lang {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "language")
    private Language language;

    private String title;

    @Column(name = "text", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String text;

    @Column(name = "plaintext", columnDefinition = "TEXT")
    private String plaintext;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)//, mappedBy = "articles_lang")
    @JoinColumn(name = "pages_lang")
    private List<Images> images;
```

When I persist (create) in the DB whit this method, it works without any problem :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<String> postPageTopLevel(@RequestBody Pages posted) {
Pages inserted = new Pages();
inserted.merge(posted);

Pages result = dao.save(inserted);

HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.setLocation(ServletUriComponentsBuilder
        .fromCurrentRequest().path("/" + result.getId())
        .buildAndExpand(result.getId()).toUri());

return new ResponseEntity<String>(getGson().toJson(result), httpHeaders, HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

But when I want to update an attribute of the Pages_lang object and I persist the Page object, the attribute isn't modified on the DB.

Here, the method to update :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<String> putPage(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Pages puted) {
    System.out.println("");System.out.println("");System.out.println("");System.out.println("");System.out.println("");System.out.println("");

    if (id != puted.getId())
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("URI unmatch element", new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);

    Pages page = dao.findOne(id);
    if (page == null)
        return new ResponseEntity<String>(null, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);

    dao.save(puted);

    return new ResponseEntity<String>(getGson().toJson(puted), new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I think the problem is related with the Cascade type of the Pages_lang attribute in the Pages Object.

Anyone can help me ?

Regards

Edit :

The dao.save() method is the basic method included in the Spring Repository.

BaseRepository.java

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRepository<T, ID extends Serializable> extends Repository<T, ID> {

void delete(T deleted);

Iterable<T> findAll();

T findOne(ID id);

T save(T persisted);

Iterable<T> save(Iterable<T> persited);
}
```

Comment: For starters, try changing your `id` to `Long`. It's customary to use a null value to represent "hasn't been persisted yet", and odd things can happen with primitives.

Comment: I'm inclined to suspect that declaring `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` (as opposed to a broader cascading specification) when mapping `Pages.pages_lang` might have something to do with it, but that depends on the provenance of the `Pages` instance and on the behavior of `dao.save()`, which you have not presented.

Comment: Hello, I've tried to change the id to Long instead of long but the problem is still here.